# how to get DOMTEXT with DBMS_XMLDOM on PL/SQL

Tags: sql, database, plsql, oracle11g, xmldom

i'm trying to get the text value from my xml with DBMS_XMLDOM.
For example in:

```
<Vehicle>
    <Cars name ="Tesla">Model-S</Cars>
</Vehicle>
```

I want to get "Model-S" as Varchar2.
It seems that i can't find any function like getTextNode/getTextValue.
What is the proper way to get the value from the DomText?

So far i got :

```
set serveroutput on size 1000000; 
DECLARE     
  xmlDomElement         xmldom.DOMElement; 
  xmlDomDokument        xmldom.DOMDocument; 
  v_xml    clob; 
BEGIN           
  v_xml := 
   '<Vehicle> 
      <Car> 
        <Tesla>Model-X</Tesla> 
      </Car> 
    </Vehicle>'; 

  xmlDomDokument := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument(v_xml) ; 
  xmlDomElement :=  dbms_xmldom.getdocumentelement(xmlDomDokument); 
  xmlDomNode :=  dbms_xmldom.makeNode(xmlDomElement);   
  dbms_output.put_line( 'Print node Vehicle : ' || dbms_xmldom.getnodename(xmlDomNode)); 

  -- Question: is there something like "dbms_xmldom.getTextValue"?   

end;
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Ivan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For getting the value of the text node, you can use XMLDOM.GETNODEVALUE. But to use that, you need to get the first child of the node xmldom.getFirstChild(n). Use the block below to get your output

```
DECLARE     
  xmlDomElement         xmldom.DOMElement; 
  xmlDomDokument        xmldom.DOMDocument; 
  xmlDomNode            xmldom.DOMNode; 
  lv_domnodelist1       dbms_xmldom.DomNodeList;
  lv_domnodelist2       dbms_xmldom.DomNodeList;
  v_xml    clob; 
BEGIN           
  v_xml := 
   '<Vehicle> 
      <Car> 
        <Tesla>Model-X</Tesla> 
      </Car> 
    </Vehicle>'; 

  xmlDomDokument := dbms_xmldom.newDomDocument(v_xml) ; 
  xmlDomElement :=  dbms_xmldom.getdocumentelement(xmlDomDokument); 
  xmlDomNode :=  dbms_xmldom.makeNode(xmlDomElement);   
  lv_domnodelist1 := DBMS_XMLDOM.GETCHILDNODES(xmlDomNode);

  For i in 0..dbms_xmldom.getLength( lv_domnodelist1 ) - 1 loop
    xmlDomNode := DBMS_XMLDOM.ITEM(lv_domnodelist1,i);
    lv_domnodelist2 := DBMS_XMLDOM.GETCHILDNODES(xmlDomNode);
    FOR J in 0..dbms_xmldom.getLength( lv_domnodelist2 ) - 1 loop
      xmlDomNode := DBMS_XMLDOM.ITEM(lv_domnodelist2,J);
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Print node Name : ' ||  dbms_xmldom.getnodename(xmlDomNode)); 
      xmlDomNode := DBMS_XMLDOM.getFirstChild(xmlDomNode);
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Print node Value : ' || dbms_xmldom.getnodevalue(xmlDomNode)); 
    end loop;
  end loop;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Walking the DOM seems like overkill here; you can use an XQuery:

```
select XMLQuery('/Vehicle/Car/Tesla/text()'
  passing XMLType('<Vehicle> 
      <Car> 
        <Tesla>Model-X</Tesla> 
      </Car> 
    </Vehicle>')
  returning content) as model
from dual;

MODEL             
------------------
Model-X
```

If you need more information you can get more fields; and with multiple nodes you can use XMLTable instead:

```
select *
from XMLTable('/Vehicle/Car'
  passing XMLType('<Vehicle> 
      <Car> 
        <Tesla>Model-X</Tesla> 
      </Car> 
    </Vehicle>')
  columns vehicle_type varchar2(10) path 'local-name(.)',
    vehicle_make varchar2(10) path 'local-name(./*)',
    vehicle_model varchar2(10) path '*'
);

VEHICLE_TY VEHICLE_MA VEHICLE_MO
---------- ---------- ----------
Car        Tesla      Model-X
```

Comment: Using xmldom is highly useful for parsing xml documents whose element names or structure is not known. Writing the xmldom code may be tedious, but once created it will be really helpful for parsing the whole document

Comment: @DineshV - still seems like overkill here *8-) The example may be hugely simplified of course.

Comment: @AlexPoole  Thanks for showing it. This is a different approach. But definetly correct answer too.